# Need help fetch friends from vkontakte

Tags: java, spring, security, oauth-2.0

I have written oauth2 social client but could not fetch authorized user's friends list
Please have a look at my code to see what's missing/
regards

please look at **@RequestMapping("vkontakte/friends")**

**java 1.8 spring security**

```
 @SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableOAuth2Client

public class SocialApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    OAuth2ClientContext oAuth2ClientContext;

    @RequestMapping({ "/user", "/me" })
    public Map<String, String> user(Principal principal) {
        Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        map.put("name", principal.getName());
        return map;
    }

    //TODO как это оформить на фронтенде?
    @RequestMapping("/vkontakte/friends")
    public Map<String,String> friends() {
        OAuth2RestTemplate vkTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(vk(), oAuth2ClientContext);
        UserInfoTokenServices tokenServicesvk = new UserInfoTokenServices(vkResource().getUserInfoUri(), vk().getClientId());
        tokenServicesvk.setRestTemplate(vkTemplate);

        ObjectNode resultNode = vkTemplate.getForObject(vkResource().getUserFriendsInfoUri(), ObjectNode.class);
        ArrayNode data = (ArrayNode) resultNode.get("data");
        Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        for (JsonNode dataNode : data) {
            //TODO надо как то правильно все получить?

        }

        return map;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to fetch friends from Vkontakte, you must declare a friend object, which will contain all the fields JSON structure of a friend has.

According to [documentation](https://vk.com/dev/apps.getFriendsList), every friend has an id, first name, and last name, however, the response object is a little bit more complex than we need, so you might remove what you do not need.

Assuming we need all of the attributes of the response we can come up with two objects: result and friend.

Vkontakte friend object

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class VkontakteFriend {

    private Long id;

    @JsonProperty("first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @JsonProperty("last_name")
    private String lastName;
}
```

Generic result object

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.util.List;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class FriendResponse {

    private Long count;
    private List<VkontakteFriend> items;

}
```

The only thing is left is to call API and get your response mapped to Java objects.

```
 vkTemplate.getForObject(vkResource().getUserFriendsInfoUri(), FriendResponse.class);
```